# Hover does not work in ggplot with facets on a shiny app

Tags: r, ggplot2, shiny

I have taken an example from [here](http://shiny.rstudio.com/articles/selecting-rows-of-data.html) which shows plot brush capabilities on `ggplot` with facets and changed it to see hover behavior. Any reason why hover does not work with facets?

```
library(shiny)
library(ggplot2)

runApp(shinyApp(
  ui <- basicPage(
    plotOutput("plot1", hover = "plot_hover", height = 250),
    verbatimTextOutput("info")
  ),
  server = function(input, output) {
    output$plot1 <- renderPlot({
      ggplot(mtcars, aes(x=wt, y=mpg)) + geom_point() +
        facet_grid(. ~ cyl) +
        theme_bw()
    })
    output$info <- renderPrint({
      input$plot_hover
    })
  }
))
```

Comment: when I move the cursor over any of your points I see the x and y values changing in the print area.

Comment: Reinstalled libraries and it worked.